# Searching for special characters in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field `name` in my index with value `$$$ LTD`
Standard analyser is applied to this field.

I'm trying to search for record with this value as below but nothing found.

`http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search?q=name:$$$`

In the same time when I'm searching for `name:"$$$ LTD"` it returns all records that contains `LTD` as if `$$$` ignored.

I'm quite sure proper value exists in index. So how can I search for it?

UPD.
Mapping related to searchable field:

```
{“name":{"type":"string","boost":4.0,"analyzer”:”nameAnalyzer"}

{"nameAnalyzer":{"filter":["lowercase"],"type":"custom","tokenizer":"standard"}}}
```

Comment: Can you share your mapping, i.e. what you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/my-index` ?

Comment: There are lot's of fields in index. I've added mapping details for field `name`. Let me know if anything else needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Not use Special charactor ($) in your URL parameters.So use encode of it,for Ex. encode of $ is %24 so use this way.**

```
http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search?q=name:%24%24%24
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Standard tokeniser strips special characters.

I have to define different type of tokeniser (probably space based).
More information on this question can be found on page: 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-index-special-characters-and-search-those-special-characters-in-elasticsearch/42506/2